# Updating Gemfile from Gemfile.lock, to freeze gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

After generating a Gemfile.lock from Gemfile, is there any tool to round-trip back to freeze versions in the Gemfile. I'd rather avoid doing it manually.

Background: It's good practice to freeze minor version on gems, e.g. if Gemfile.lock is 2.4.1, I'd want to update Gemfile to include ~> 2.4 ([as explained here](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/)).

Comment: That sounds like a good gem to create!  if it doesn't exist I'll make it!

Comment: @drhenner Judging from the tumbleweeds here, it looks like it doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

You should define the gem verions that you wanna freeze your app to in the GemFile itself before you run bundle install. 
Once, you have that define and you run `bundle install`, it will generate a Gemfile.lock with the versions of all installed gems and their dependancies.

again, .lock file is auto-generated ans should not be manually editted. this is what the GemFile is for.

Comment: I get that's the standard procedure, but I'm looking for something more clever to deal with upgrading of minor versions.